# Access Character for searchable feature in iOS 15

Tags: swiftui

How can I access every single typed character in the searchable field?

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(movieListVM.movies, id: \.imdbId) { movie in
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    AsyncImage(url: movie.poster
                        , content: { image in
                            image.resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 100)
                    }, placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    })
                    Text(movie.title)
                }
            }.listStyle(.plain)
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Movies")
        }
    }
```

searchText is getting populated but I want to fire an event every time a user adds a character in the search field.

Comment: Try [`onChange`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange)

Comment: Thanks a million. If you can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`onChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)) modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<10, id: \.self) { movie in
                Text("\(movie)")
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .searchable(text: $searchText)

            /// here!
            .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in
                print("searchText changed: \(searchText)")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Movies")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Print statement executed whenever searchText changes]